# Linking the pressing of Enter to a button click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some bottons on a modal form:

```
<div class="block-footer align-right">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<button type="button">Submit &amp; Close</button>
<button type="button">Close</button>
</div>
```

How can I make it so the when a user clicks on the Enter key then the first of the buttons "Submit" is "clicked". It's important for the click action as I want the user to visually see the color of the button change as it is clicked.

Note that I already did the following and tied the execution of a function to that button:

```
$('#modal button:contains("Submit")').click(function () {
    submitHandler(dObj.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
});
```

Comment: Note that if the user has already tabbed to one of the buttons and they press Enter then they will expect that button to be activated.

Comment: @Anne : please accept the answer if it served your purpose..if not then please tell us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will detect 'Enter' key press

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        $('#Submit').click();   
    }

});
```

Comment: Just a note, in JS you can do `event.keyCode || event.which` as an alternative to `(event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which)` because the `||` operator just returns the second operand if the first value is falsey (null, NaN, etc.). Good answer! +1

Comment: Further to what @nbrooks said, if you're using jQuery you can just say `event.which` because jQuery normalises it to work cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

How about handling submit() instead?

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){

    //some validation

    return false; //dont allow submit
});
```

Comment: There's a form on my modal but the buttons are not inside the form. I think given that what you suggest would not worK.

Comment: then maybe from that button call the submit to the form itself, $('form#id').submit();