# How can I add a class to an element when enter button pressed

Tags: jquery, addclass, enter

I have a modal form:

```
<button class="float-right" type="submit">Login</button>
```

```
<div class="block-footer align-right">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<button type="button">Submit &amp; Close</button>
<button type="button">Close</button>
</div>
```

How can I make it so the when a user clicks on the Enter key then the first of the buttons "Submit" is "clicked". It's important for the click action as I want the user to visually see the color of the button change as it is clicked.

Note that I already did the following and tied the execution of a function to that button:

```
$('#modal button:contains("Submit")').click(function () {
    submitHandler(dObj.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
});
```

Comment: take alook at (link)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491619/how-to-add-class-on-click-with-jquery-to-list-item?rq=1]

Comment: Other than the title, isn't this the same as your previous question:  [Linking the pressing of Enter to a button click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407420/linking-the-pressing-of-enter-to-a-button-click-with-jquery)

Comment: lol @nnnnnn good detection, but this answer is better

Comment: Anne, please don't ask questions more than once, as it creates wasted duplicate effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) { // when Enter key is pressed trigger click event for first button 
      $('.block-footer button:first').addClass('active').trigger('click')
   }
});
```